# Use a subrange of all arguments in a Bash function

Tags: bash, bash-function

I have this function in a Bash script:

```
comp() {
    rsync -v --archive $1/ $TMP/$2 $3 $4 $5 $6 $7 $8 $9
}
```

As you can see, I'm doing something special with arguments `$1` and `$2`. Then I hackily just append all the rest of them to the end of the command. They go to `$9`, but in fact all should be appended.

There must be an easier way for this?

Comment: Note that anything above `$9` needs to appear in braces (e.g. `${10}`).

Comment: @JonahBishop Yeah, that caused some weird issues for me.

Answer (score 5):

You can use substring expansion, which might be useful in certain situations. For this, though, I must say I prefer Brian's solution of shifting, as it is a bit clearer. (Also, Brian's solution is POSIX; substring expansion is a bash extension.)

```
comp () {

    rsync -v --archive "$1"/ "$TMP/$2" "${@:3}"

}
```

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't necessarily call it "easier," but you can do this:

```
comp() {
    archive=$1
    tempfile=$2
    shift 2
    rsync -v --archive $archive/ $TMP/$tempfile "$@"
}
```

That saves you from having to hard-code $3 through $11.